# Remove listener that uses a closure from array

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an array of listeners inside a singleton class called `NetworkManager` that have a completion block that gets called when something happens:

```
typealias NetworkStatusListener = (_ status: Reachability.Connection) -> ()
var listeners = [NetworkStatusListener]()
```

I add a listener with its completion block like this:

```
func addListener(completion: @escaping NetworkStatusListener){
    listeners.append(completion)
}
```

When I want to call the listeners I use this code:

```
for listener in listeners {
    listener(reachability.connection)
}
```

I'm adding a listener from a class like this:

```
NetworkManager.shared.addListener { status in
    //...
}
```

Now when this class is deinited I want to make sure that it does not keep trying to call the completion block for the listener of the deinited class. How can I do that?

Comment: an array has a `remove(at:)` method for removing its elements.. but I guess you know that. try to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I updated it, hopefully that makes it more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something similar in my code, I wrote something like this:

```
func removeListener(listener: NetworkStatusListener) {
    listeners = listeners.filter { $0 as AnyObject !== listener as AnyObject }
}
```

That check will do a reference check, so as long as you have the reference of the listener to remove this should work fine.  If not you can change the filter closure to use an id, or some other distinguishing factor.